# Logo image won't align exactly to center

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything, but nothing works! transform: translate (50%); seems to work, but it doesn't align it to the exact center. I even tried left: 50%; with it.

I've spent a week figuring it out, and I still can't.

The image I'm trying to align is a logo with the dimensions 660 X 150.

```
<div id="rectangle"> </div>

<img class="logo" src="Untitled.png">

    <style> 

        .logo {
            position: fixed; 
            width: 35%;
            top: -5px;
            height: auto;

        }

        #rectangle {
            width: 100%;
            height:100px;
            background:#101010;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;

        }


    </style>
```

EDIT: No, I want to align the logo to the center of the page. The rectangle div is the background color for the logo.

Also, none of those answers worked. :(

Comment: you need to add image in container div and then make align center.

Comment: I can't understand your question properly. You want to align your logo(660px X 150px) center of the 'rectangle' div.. is that ?? and align center means is that horizontally or vertically or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

Use `display: flex; justify-content: center;` element to align `img` at center.

```html
<div id="rectangle" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;"> 

<img class="logo" src="Untitled.png">
</div>
    <style> 

        .logo {
            position: relative; 
            width: 35%;
            top: -5px;
            height: auto;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #rectangle {
        
            width: 100%;
            height:100px;
            background:#101010;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;

        }


    </style>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

`center` is a deprecated tag in HTML5. Avoid using it.

Comment: better now. @Mr.Roshan

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `<img>` tag, try using a div and give that image as backgorund with

```
background-position: center;
background-image=url('image.png');
backgorund-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div id="rectangle"><img class="logo" src="Untitled.png"></div>
```

and for style

```
<style> 

    .logo {
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
    }

    #rectangle {
        width: 100%;
        height:100px;
        vertical-align:center;
    }


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<div id="rectangle"> </div>

<img class="logo" src="Untitled.png">
</div>
    <style> 

        .logo {
            width: 35%;
             height: 150px;
             }

  #rectangle {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
     background: #101010;
     text-align: center;
   }




    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?
And yes, avoid using `center` tag as its deprecated in HTML5.

```css
.center-my-content {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle" class="center-my-content">
  <img class="logo" src="http://www.harpseals.org/images/seals/whitecoat_on_back-photo-eric_baccega_npl-sm.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove the `position: fixed;` from the img.

---

```css
.logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 35%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -5px;
}

#rectangle {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #101010;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="rectangle">
  <img class="logo" src="image.png"></div>
```